# Pycharm can't find the python(conda env) packages

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm using a conda env as python interpreter and I've all the necessary packages installed
[image] 
But when I run the file, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16,
 in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming Projects/python projects/MaskRCNN/src/test_tf.py", line 8
, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in
<module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, i
n <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, i
n <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11
, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26,
 in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

But when I run it from the terminal, it works just fine

[image]
Does anyone have any clue on what might be a fix?

Comment: Could you open a terminal, activate your environment (`$ source activate tf`), then type `$ python` and when the python prompt (`>>>`) appears enter: `>>> import sys; print(sys.executable);`. What is the output?

Comment: I get `D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\python.exe`; also I'm on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, my first port of call would have been to verify the python executable being used by both pycharm and terminal. Then to check that your PATH was the same in both. This looks to be the fine though and user2235698 seems to think its a known issue, I've not got much more to offer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234), should be fixed in [2019.1 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/). Could you please update and check?